# Re-assigning multiple IDs upon delete

Tags: jquery

I have the below HTML.

```
<ul>
    <li id="myli-1">
        <input id="name-1" />
        <input id="surname-1" /> 
        <span class="remove">X</span>
    </li>
    <li id="myli-2">
        <input id="name-2" />
        <input id="surname-2" />   
        <span class="remove">X</span>
    </li>
    <li id="myli-3">
        <input id="name-3" />
        <input id="surname-3" /> 
        <span class="remove">X</span>
    </li>
    <li id="myli-4">
        <input id="name-4" />
        <input id="surname-4" /> 
        <span class="remove">X</span>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

User removes the **second** item with clicking on the second **X**

```
$(".remove").live('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

How can I make the **id** s of below items `myli-3, name-3, surname-3, myli-4` etc. to reduce by one ?

I created this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZcY5/1/),

Comment: Do you need to use IDs like this in a dynamic list? It may be smarter to drop the IDs and avoid the tricky re-assignment. Instead, once you're ready to do something with them, you can grab them all with jQuery (and assign them indices at that point, if needed).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because `.live()` is not available in the version of jQuery that you selected. Here's an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/QZcY5/3/

Comment: Use this for your click function:`$("body").on('click', ".remove", function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });`

Comment: If it is a form you are working on then I suggest you assign your input names as arrays `name[1]`, then when the form submits you can loop through all elements in the array even if they are not sequential so there's no need to adjust indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a custom filter jquery. By the way .live() is deprecated since 1.7

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZcY5/2/)

Try

```
 $(".remove").click(function() 
 {
       $(this).parent().remove();
       refreshIndex();
 });

 function refreshIndex()
 {
     $('ul li').filter(hasIdWithIndex).each(updateIdWithIndex);
     $('ul li input').filter(hasIdWithIndex).each(updateIdWithIndex);

    function hasIdWithIndex()
    {
     return this.id.search(/\d$/) != -1;
    }

    function updateIdWithIndex()
    {
        var $this   = $(this);
        var id      = this.id;
        var index   = $this.closest('li').index();

        id          = this.id.substring(0, id.length -1); 
        this.id     = id + index; 
   }

}
```

Comment: In order to keep the "live" functionality, you should use this for the click logic: `$("body").on('click', ".remove", function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });` That way you avoid needing to unbind/rebind on new insertions.

Comment: I agree but I would use $("ul"), I like to try to keep my scope small.